# Use case of IEqualityComparer<TKey> on generic dictionary

Tags: c#, generics

Today while researching for a project I was looking through the docs for [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). There I found some remark I may have overlooked in the past:

*Because keys can be inherited and their behavior changed, their absolute uniqueness cannot be guaranteed by comparisons using the Equals method.*

This same remark seems to be sprinkled all over the docs for most (keyed) collection classes I looked at afterwards. But I wasn't able to find any examples that illustrate the potential problem described, although I'm quite sure that this is what the constructors accepting an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` are for, and that it arises when complex types are being used as keys.

Can anyone explain to me under which circumstances one might run into a problem this comment points at? As long as I don't know exactly how or when such a problem may arise, I can't design to allow for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takrl,

Say a you're processing a big query result on a server: you're building a big `Dictionary<Student, List<Result>>`... and meanwhile someone-else mutates **the identity** of a Student object in the shared-model underneath you (say someone changes "Bob"s first name to "Fred"). If the Name attribute contributes to Students' Equals (and HashCode) method then the next time you try to add a Result for "Bob" to your Dictionary, you won't FIND the object-which-represents-Bob in the Dictionary, simply because the "Bob" object's HashCode has changed... so his existing results are "lost".

Hence: One of the tricks with using any class as-a-key is to make it's **Identity fields** (those used in equals and HashCode methods) **immutable**.

In practice, this won't matter until you're accessing your model from multiple threads concurrently. In a single-threaded environment you really don't have to worry, simply because YOU won't be silly enough to mutate an Identity you need WHILE you need it.

Does that make sense?

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: Thanks for that, Keith. If I understand you correctly, basically that means a) the potential problem really only exists for complex types being used as keys and b) whenever I want to use a complex type as a key I either have to override Equals() and GetHashCode() on that object in a sensible way ([great article with basic guidelines on that here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx)), or use an equality comparer in the constructor?

Comment: Ummm, No I meant what I said. A pre-requisite of reliable Hashing is that the **Identity of the objects being hashed is immutable** such that _bobsStoredHashCode ALLWAYS equals bob.GetHashCode(); for the bob-objects lifetime. Basically, If you're going to use Person as key, make it's Identity Fields (say FirstName, Surname, and DateOfBirth) **readonly**. Then ALL Person contructors must allows these fields to be set; and once the contructor has returned these values are immutable. Any change to Bob's identity forces creation of a NEW Person object. Note the "basic types" are all immutable!

Answer (score 2):

Using any object/value as a key is not as trivial as it sounds, as it depends on a correct implementation of Equals and GetHashCode. To be honest, the "subclass distorting things" scenario is not one I've hugely encountered, however a more common use of this API is to allow usage when the type you are using as the key doesn't provide a suitable Equals/GetHashCode, and is outside of your control. For example, you want to use `Customer` as a key, but you only want to match on the `Id` (i.e. you don't want the default reference equality behaviour; maybe you are handling different objects from different sources, and need different instances to be considered equal based on the `Id`). In this scenario you could write a custom equality comparer that considers only the `Id`.

Personally, though; I'm a fan of simple. I ***very rarely*** (if ever) index on anything except `int`, `string`, etc. This keeps things simple - and at the same time shows another common scenario: providing a case-sensitive/insensitive or culture-sensitive/insensitive comparer for a `string` key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Same here, I can't remember using a complex type as a key in the past. Good point about culture/case-in/sensitive comparison, I'll keep that in mind for future use.

Comment: Not being TOO picky but: "you want to use Customer as a key, but you only want to match on the Id"... So which is it? Do you want to user Customer or Customer.Id as a key? You're being lazy and don't want to create a value-wrapper-class to hold Customer as well as there other interesting attributes? Don't get me wrong, Lazy is GOOD! and in this case a custom Comparer is just the ticket, so long as no-bugger changes a Customer.Id ;-)

Comment: @corlettk let's assume it was immutable ;p